# How to solve binding to const/non-const types?

Tags: types, compiler-construction, mutable

*This question is about compiler internals*.

Consider a language like C++ or D which has the notion of `const` type. For example one could write:

```
const Foo a = ...; // a is of type "const Foo"
Foo b = ...;
```

And I am interested here in binding to a type -- how is it done?

For now I can only think (sorry for crazy amateur ideas) -- of doubling entire type tree, making for each type `T` its const twin and putting it as a parent. Another would be to bind as usual (as with language with no such distinction) however making binding richer with info whether the binding itself is for `const` type or not.

But how is it solved for real?

Comment: I'm not an expert on the subject, but I'd say the `const` is an attribute of the declaration, not of the type.

Comment: @GerardvanHelden, I am not sure I follow, you see somewhere in the code `a`, how would you get type info about the type? For example consider third line `b = a;`.

Comment: It depends on what you think the compiler should do in such a case. Is 'a' const, or is 'a' of a const type, such that b is now implicitly const as well? Is that an error, or does it imply a value copy?

Comment: @GerardvanHelden, here I am for non-/const types. So `a` is of const type. I am asking how the binding would work for the line as `b = a;`.